# Instantiate then forward parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-meta-programming

I'm looking to have this type of object templated:

```cpp
struct Impl{
    static bool func(Foo& a, Bar& b) {
        return true; // arbitrary code, ignore this
    }
    static bool func() {
        Foo a;
        Bar b;
        return func(a, b);
    }
};
```

How can I write `ImplT` so parameters get initialized and forwarded, as shown above?

```cpp
template<typename...Args>
struct ImplT{
    static bool func(Args&...) {
        return true;    
    }
    
    static bool func() {
        // error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Foo&' to an rvalue of type 'Foo'
        return func(Args{}...);
    }

};
```

Comment: `static bool func(const Args&...)` or `static bool func(Args&&...)`.

Comment: Or `return [](Args&&... args) { return func(args...); }(Args{}...);`

Comment: @273K I had written: `static bool func(Args&&... args) { return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);  }` but it was giving me infinite recursion at compile time :( Why doesn't work with forward, but is okay with simply `return func(args...);` ?

Comment: You need to change `func(Args&...)` to `func(Args&&..)` or `func(const Args&..)`. You should not change `func()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::tuple` and `std::apply`

```
template<typename...Args>
struct ImplT{
    static bool func(Args&...) {
        return true;    
    }
    
    static bool func() {
        std::tuple<Args...> args;
        bool(*f)(Args&...) = func;
        return std::apply(f, args);
    }

};
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d83d1e843b2cb6b)

Comment: @Barry `func` is an overload set, you need to disambiguate

Comment: Oh I didn't realize they have the same name. That's... weird. Ok.